# ¿Cómo transformar minutos en días?

Tags: php

Ejemplo, en mi base de datos tengo una tabla de un baneo que dura aproximadamente 1440 minutos (1 día) ¿cómo puedo transformar esos minutos en días? O sea, en base al número de minutos, obtener un número de días.

```php
<?php if($top["ban_length"] == 0)                                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                                               
?>                                                                                                                                              
    <i>Permanente</i>                                                                                                                           
<?php }                                                                                                                                         
else if($top["ban_type"] == NO)                                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                                               
?>                                                                                                                                              
    <i>Expirada</i>                                                                                                                             
<?php }                                                                                                                                         
else                                                                                                                                            
{                                                                                                                                               
?>                                                                                                                                              
<?php echo $top["ban_length"] ?> //Esto es lo que quiero transformar                                                                            
<?php } ?>
```

Así se ve en mi tabla. Quiero transformarlo para que solo diga 1 día. Claro, hay baneos que pueden durar 2 días, 15 días, etc.

[image: Así se ve en mi tabla. Quiero transformarlo para que solo diga 1 da, claro hay baneos que pueden durar que si 2 dias, 15 dias etc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un simple cálculo matemático se puede convertir los minutos a días.

Como bien dijiste, un día tiene `1440` minutos. Si se divide `$tiempoBaneadoEnMinutos` por `1440` obtenés el número de días.

Ejemplo:

```php
$tiempoBaneadoEnMinutos = 1440;
$diasBaneados = $tiempoBaneadoEnMinutos / 1440;
// $diasBaneados = 1 (día)

$tiempoBaneadoEnMinutos = 2880;
$diasBaneados = $tiempoBaneadoEnMinutos / 1440;
// Resultado = 2 (días)
```

Para redondear la división y que no te den número flotantes podrías usar la función [floor](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.floor.php).

```php
$tiempoBaneadoEnMinutos = 5000;
$diasBaneados = $tiempoBaneadoEnMinutos / 1440;
// Resultado = 3,47 (días)

$diasBaneados = floor($tiempoBaneadoEnMinutos / 1440);
// Resultado = 3 (días)
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió tu método.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que solo es cuestión de darle formato a la variable que te entrega los 1440 minutos, algo como esto:

```
<?php
function convert_seconds($seconds) 
 {
  $dt1 = new DateTime("@0");
  $dt2 = new DateTime("@$seconds");
  return $dt1->diff($dt2)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
  }
echo convert_seconds(200000)."\n";
?>
```

el resultado sería:

```
2 days, 7 hours, 33 minutes and 20 seconds
```

Fuente: [w3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/php-exercises/php-date-exercise-21.php)

Comment: Pero con mi variable como quedaría ya que en si los minutos no bajan quedan estaticos por lo que añadirles horas, minutos y segundos no quedaria? me podrías ayudar apenas estoy aprendiendo php

Comment: Perdon, queda fijo